# Unicode icons: sometimes looks like a wrong encoding

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, unicode, google-chrome-extension

In my CSS I have this (unrelated code is omitted):

```
.selector:after {
    content: '▾';
}
```

Normally it looks like this:

[image: unicode icon ▾]

But *sometimes* I open [my browser extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/text-to-speech-that-bring/eidcpcpmmfiolomceegcagooodnaplmp) and see this `â–¾`:

[image: unicode icon broken encoding ▾]

In devtools I see the same:

[image: devtools encoding â–¾]

Why this happens? How can I fix it?

Comment: Make sure to save the html file in UTF-8 encoding and also add `<meta charset="UTF-8">` inside `<head>`. It seems your files are fine so that could be a bug in Chrome. If you can find a reliable sequence of actions to reproduce it, consider reporting on https://crbug.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-css-charset

If it's a separate style sheet resource, add `@charset "UTF-8";` to the response body and `Content-Type: text/css; charset=UTF-8` to the response header.

Comment: Interesting... just to the first line of CSS I need to add `@charset "UTF-8";`? This is a browser extension so looks like I cannot control the response header. Thank you, I will try.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but in case it helps someone: Here is how I fixed it in ASP.NET Core 7

```
var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider(); // (to specify content type and charset for css responses)
provider.Mappings[".css"] = "text/css; charset=UTF-8";
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    ContentTypeProvider = provider
});
```

This configures the static file serving middleware and tells it to put the specified header into files that end with `.css` extension.