# Unicode Characters From CSS "Sometimes" Render As Gibberish (â–¾)

Tags: css, asp.net-core, unicode, datatables, bootstrap-5

[image]

The problem is that sometimes, randomly (approximately in 1 out of 100 page refresh), the unicode characters in my page appear as gibberish (you will probably have to zoom in to see it clearly). More specifically, the unicode characters are rendered as `â–¾`. I don't know what it means or why it could be happening. The characters that break are the sort indicators on the columns, and the tick of the checkboxes.

I use DataTables UI library with its bootstrap integration, and the definition of these characters/signs come from `dataTables.bootstrap5.css`. There is no network issue, and css file gets served to the client when the issue happens. However, the content of the css file gets broken (see DevTools inspection comparison in the image).

The back-end of the project is asp.net core 7, and it's an MVC project.
In the `head` section of the project, I already have this specified to support utf8 character set:
`<meta charset="utf-8" />`

I have tried replacing the arrows in css with unicode characters like `"\f0d8"` (this is "caret up" symbol), but it just appeared as squares.

Please note, this question is NOT code-related, so please don't flag the question with "code needed".

Comment: Especially Chrome is known to sometimes not interpret a stylesheet in the correct encoding, if not explicitly told about it. The best solution in my experience is to add an [`@charset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@charset) into the stylesheet - but with external libraries like you are dealing with here, that is probably not the best option. So try and make your server return those resources with a `Content-Type: text/css; charset=UTF-8` header, https://stackoverflow.com/a/55762978/1427878

Comment: @CBroe `@charset "UTF-8";` already seems to be present at the top of the css file in question. I will try to explicitly specify headers somehow, thanks for your reply

Comment: If it only replicates sometimes are you certain it isn't a timing problem? e.g. the font not being loaded at the point the system interprets that bit of CSS? While text in the DOM will I believe get repainted I'm not sure whether this is true for CSS.

Comment: @AHaworth good thinking, but it is not a font. It's unicode characters, and they are being inserted by the CSS with `:before`.  As per @CBroe's suggestion, I have updated my static file server middleware to append `Content-Type: text/css; charset=UTF-8` header (content type was already being set correctly, but charset was not being specified). Thus far, the problem did not reproduce. I will see if it happens again :)

Comment: If that was the solution, I will answer my own question later with the code I wrote to configure asp.net core static file middleware.

Comment: Did you look at https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/67960/content-a-in-ordering-arrows ?

Comment: @fatm it seems they were able to solve the issue by adding `@charset "UTF-8";` at the top of their CSS, however, this was not sufficient for me. I suppose the underlying framework plays a role in this. Perhaps his web server was adding proper charset specification in response headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code that fixed the problem on ASP.NET Core 7;

```
var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider(); // (to specify content type and charset for css responses)
provider.Mappings[".css"] = "text/css; charset=UTF-8";
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    ContentTypeProvider = provider
});
```

This updates the static file server middleware to append `Content-Type: text/css; charset=UTF-8` header data when serving static files with `.css` file extension. Content type was already being set correctly before, but charset was not being specified, which was causing the issue on Google Chrome. Explicitly specifying charset solved the issue. Thank you @Cbroe